# Why do I got TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object when using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark to deal with my data, like that:

```
        dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
            url='jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx',
            driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
            dbtable='(select * from test_table where id > 100) t',
            user='xxxxxx',
            password='xxxxxx'
        ).load()

        result = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dataframe_mysql, 1)
```

But I got this error from spark:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/private/var/www/http/hawk-scripts/hawk_etl/scripts/spark_rds_to_parquet.py", line 46, in 
> process()
> File "/private/var/www/http/hawk-scripts/hawk_etl/scripts/spark_rds_to_parquet.py", line 36, in process
> result = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dataframe_mysql, 1).map(func)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 574, in parallelize
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 611, in _serialize_to_jvm
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 211, in dump_stream
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 133, in dump_stream
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 143, in _write_with_length
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 427, in dumps
> TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Am I using it wrong? How should I use SparkContext.parallelize to deal with DataFrame?

Comment: `dataframe_mysql` is already a dataframe when you get it from the call to `.load()`. You don't need the call to `parallelize` and you don't use `parallelize` to manipulate dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, `dataframe_mysql` is already a `Dataframe`, if want to get a `RDD`, just use `dataframe.rdd` instead of `parallelize`